# remove all white space and all line breaks and character

Tags: jquery

I have tried several tutorials , but could not get anything to work. I want to remove all the the html space charactors , plus the line between, and then remove all line breaks and any white space. I have no access to change the html or this would be much easier

```
&nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

from the following

```
<span class="weekly-navbar"><span class="reportnavigationheader">Select Week: </span><span class="currentweek">1</span>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">2</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">3</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">4</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">5</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">6</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">7</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">8</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">9</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">10</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">11</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">12</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">13</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">14</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">15</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">16</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">17</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">18</a>
</span>
```

so html looks like this when done

```
<span class="weekly-navbar"><span class="reportnavigationheader">Select Week: </span><span class="currentweek">1</span><a href="#">2</a><a href="#">3</a><a href="#">4</a><a href="#">5</a><a href="#">6</a><a href="#">7</a><a href="#">8</a><a href="#">9</a><a href="#">10</a><a href="#">11</a><a href="#">12</a><a href="#">13</a><a href="#">14</a><a href="#">15</a><a href="#">16</a><a href="#">17</a><a href="#">18</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use this [`HTML minifier`](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) framework

Comment: i am not writing any html , nor have access to the html , so i'm left to fix the issue after the fact